# Laravel request validation allow only if user id is the same as the logged one

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I need to check in the rules (or authorize) if user can be authorized to delete his comment. ho can i do it? here's my rules

```
        'user_id' => [
            'required',
            'exists:user,id',
        ],
```

I'm checking here if the user exists but how can i checked if user is the same as the logged one?

Right now I'm checking it in controller

```
public function destroy(CommentDestroyRequest $request, Comment $comment)
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    if ($comment->user_id !== $userId)
        return response()->json(null, Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN); 
}
```

but I wanted to move it

Comment: What have you tried from the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Comment: of course, can you point me to any specific chapter? I couldn't find anything

Comment: You have to make code to check in blade file if the comment is from logged in user  or not.

Comment: i'm not using blade, as I'm developing it in Vue, but frontend protects it, nevertheless I want to check it on the backend too

Answer (score 2):

The context of the question is not correct. You are trying to use input validation to authorize users.

First; if you want to use logged in user's id to create a new record, you don't need to post it from a form, just use `$request->user()->id` or `Auth::id()` as you did. To make sure there is always an authenticated user; add `auth` middleware for that route (or controller method).

And on the other hand if you want to check if a user authorized to do something you should use authorization services which comes built-in with Laravel.

To accomplish that you can use `Gate` or `Policy`

Here is the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Let's say you want to determine if a user authorized to delete a `Comment` , you can do this by [Writing Gates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-gates)

You can define gates in your `app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php` file's `boot` method;

```
// app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('delete-comment', function (User $user, Comment $comment) {
        return $user->id === $comment->user_id;
    });
}
```

Now you can use that gate with it's name -which is `delete-comment` here- to check authorization.

```
public function destroy(CommentDestroyRequest $request, Comment $comment)
{
    if (Gate::denies('delete-comment', $comment)) abort(403);
    
    // Authorization checked, you can do whatever you want
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect('/comments');
}
```

Or you can use `authorize` in a controller;

```
public function destroy(CommentDestroyRequest $request, Comment $comment)
{
    $this->authorize('delete-comment', $comment);
    
    // Authorization checked, you can do whatever you want
    $comment->delete();
    return redirect('/comments');
}
```

This will do the trick for you.

But a more convenient way to authorization in Laravel is [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies). You should definitely check and consider to use them.

> Policies are classes that organize authorization logic around a
> particular model or resource. For example, if your application is a
> blog, you may have a `App\Models\Post` model and a corresponding
> `App\Policies\PostPolicy` to authorize user actions such as creating
> or updating posts.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your user_id in comment section too so you can easily detect wether the user is authenticated or not